# Minimal distance from point to curve

Tags: geometry

### To make it short

Let's consider the following function $f(x)=a*x^b$ and any point $p(x, y)$

How to get the minimal distance between any point $p$ and the curve of $f$ ?

### What I tried

I tried to follow this protocol:

1. Write the distance function of the curve $D(x)=\sqrt((x - p.x) ^ 2 + (f(x) - p.y) ^ 2)$
2. Substitute $f$ so that $D(x) = \sqrt((x - p.x)² + (a * x ^ b - p.y)²)$
3. Derive the power of $D(x)$ such as $D²'(x) = 2 * (x - p.x) + 2 * a * b * x ^ {b - 1} * (a * x ^ b - p.y)$
4. Solve $D²'(x) = 0$ to find the $x$ coordinate at which the curve has the minimal distance to point $p$.
5. Compute the distance $D(x)$ using this $x$ coordinate.

As I am stuck at solving the equation for $x$ at step 4, I can't ensure that this reasoning is right.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!